# Is there some general lower bound for sum of squared probabilities?

Tags: probability, cryptography

In foundations of cryptography the author is trying to demonstrate the success an adversarial algorithm A1 will have using just random guessing. A1 will, given the output of some function f will try and produce its pre-image by guessing, and the author shows this probability to be greater than 2^-n. Is there any reason for this?
It also says that this sum is minimized when all the values to be squared are equal why is this obvious?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality
$(x \cdot y)^2\leq (x \cdot x)(y \cdot y)$
with equality if and only if $x$ and $y$ are parallel.

In particular, take $x = (x_1, \dots, x_n)$ and $y = (1, \dots, 1)$, so 
$$x \cdot y = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i = 1$$
$$x \cdot x = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2$$
$$y \cdot y = n$$
hence 
$$\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 \geq \frac{1}{n}.$$

Comment: Thanks for the response. Just a quick follow-up: 
Is their bound there just to be conservative? I feel like the difference between a polynomially related bound and an exponentially related one is pretty large, no? Also, any comment on the minimization of the sum only occurring when all x_i are equal?